# How to make the output of an inverter using MOSFETs and an IR2104 better using an Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm, inverter

I have been trying to build an 12 V H-bridge inverter. The output I am getting is fine up to 0.5 A as shown below:

[image]

When I increase the load the waveform shape changes as shown below. I am using an [IR2104](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IR2104-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c7c1c31671) driver and an Arduino microcontroller. Is there any way to overcome these slight bends in the waveform?

[image]

This is the schematic:
[image]

Comment: Please show the schematic and explain what power source you are using. Also explain what node on the schematic you are capturing on your oscilloscope pictures.

Comment: Im using this circuit 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3icUw.png

i guess it is due to the voltage drop across the mosfets. However the voltage drop is 1.6V for one bridge leg. Which means 0.8V for one mosfet and Rds (on)=0.8V/0.6A  = 1.33ohm.   Now if i want to operate at around 10A, the drop would be significant. What should i do?

Comment: I took your word re *12 V H-bridge* - the scope looks 18 V?! Next thing I notice is "0 V intervals" in the first image, and about the same amplitude in the second *going the other side of zero* where "the tops take a dip": GND problem *in scoping*? If not using differential probes: Exactly how/where did you connect scope GND?

Comment: Please post Vgs and Vb oscillograms.

Comment: And \$Q_1V_{DS}\$ while you're at it. Umm - U1 being a boost converter, with V_IN > 12 V  V_12 should be \$V_{IN} - V_{ESR_{L1}} - V_{F_{D1}}\$.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a grounding issue.  You can see from the my attempt at highlighting the signal below that your two images differ from each other by an offset that has your desired sinusoidal shape - likely caused by the current in your power or ground path.  Your power and ground paths may be inductive or resistive, but if you already have a good layout, the problem might disappear just by moving your scope ground closer to your measure point.

Good luck!

[image]